# PDF to Epub Converter

Tags: android, android-studio, pdf, converters, epub

I have an epub reader app. Now I want to allow pdf files to be opened with this app after converting pdf to epub.
I'm looking for good library or resources for this. I have tried the following library but it is throwing the following error:

**The library:**
[Pdf to Epub Converter Library](https://github.com/jmrozanec/pdf-converter)

**Error:**

> Failed to resolve: com.google.guava:guava:22.0-SNAPSHOT

I've looked around to resolve the problem and found that in **pom.xml** the distribution management is like below:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <name>Release Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>ossrh</id>
        <name>Snapshots Repository</name>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

but there is nothing hosted there. maybe it's been moved or removed. How can I solve this
Or is there any alternative to this library for converting pdf to epub?

Comment: I took a quick look at the github project you linked to, and note it simply converts the PDF to an image, so you will lose all text. Also, it uses ghostcript, ghost4j apparently, so that may or may not work on Android, but I assume ghost4j is your issue. But even solving that might not give you the EPUB you want.

Comment: Caution: asking for recommendations for libraries (or anything else) is out of bounds on Stack Overflow and will generally get your question closed rather quickly.

Comment: @Ryan yes. That was the issue. It didn't work. So can you recommend something for converting pdf to epub in android?

Comment: If you are looking for recommendations then post here instead: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is a question that has already been answers on the software recomendation stack exchange: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31881/library-for-converting-pdf-docx-xls-to-epub-in-android/38466#38466